# Mysql - Como selecionar os registros do mês anterior?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Olá, estou tentando selecionar os registros da tabela 'Clientes' que foram registrados no mês passado. Nessa tabela existe o campo 'CreateDate' (datetime). Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma mas não está retornando apenas os registros do mês passado, mas, sim dos meses de anos passados também. Exemplo: se o mês passado é Março a minha consulta está retornando Março de todos os anos que estão na tabela.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate FROM Clientes WHERE MONTH(CreateDate) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH));
```

Comment: Acho que consegui desta forma:

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate FROM Clientes WHERE MONTH(CreateDate) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)) AND YEAR(CreateDate) = YEAR(NOW());

Comment: O problema é que dessa forma que encontrei quando for o mês de Janeiro não retornará nada e preciso que retorne Dezembro do ano anterior. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Tente assim:

SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate
FROM Clientes
WHERE CreateDate >= DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)